# shiny app using default value from query string?

Tags: r, shiny

Consider the following shiny app, which I would like to:

1. Have an input field `seed` with a default value
2. Look at the query string for the `seed` variable
3. If the value does not exist, render using the default value.
4. IF the value exists, DO NOT render the output with the default value; instead, use the query string value

In other words, I'd like to wait for the initial rendering until I've checked to make sure that the query string doesn't specify any new default value for the field.

````
---
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

values = reactiveValues(checked_query = FALSE)
```
```

```{r}
textInput("seed", label = "Seed:", width = "150px", value = "s33d")
```

```{r}
observeEvent(input$seed, {
    query = getQueryString()
    seed = query[['seed']]
    
    if (!is.null(seed)) {
      updateTextInput(session, 'seed', value = seed)
    }else{
      values$checked_query = TRUE
    }
    
}, once = TRUE)
```

```{r}

renderUI({
  
  # if(!values$checked_query) return(HTML("Please wait..."))
  
  htmltools::tags$h3(input$seed, style="color: red;")
})
```
````

If I run the code as is with with a URL containing, say `?seed=38543`, it will very briefly show the page with `s33d` rendered then switch over to `38543`. I would like to prevent it from the initial rendering of `s33d` if the query string variable `seed` exists.

As you can see, I've made an initial try at this with a reactive value called `checked_query`. If you uncomment the first line in the `renderUI()` function, it will successfully block the initial rendering if the query string value exists, AND successfully render the initial value if it doesn't, but I'm not sure how to make it update to the query string value.

If I put

```
values$checked_query = TRUE
```

just after the `updateTextInput`, the update to the `renderUI` happens too fast and I still see the `s33d`.

Any idea how to use the query string value as the default value, but only if it exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest work around is to draw the input box at runtime as well. Rather than having the text input directly, use

```
uiOutput("seedbox")
```

and then add

```
output$seedbox <- renderUI({
  query = getQueryString()
  seed = if ('seed' %in% names(query)) query[['seed']] else "s33d"
  textInput("seed", label = "Seed:", width = "150px", value = seed)
})
```

That way the box will be drawn with the correct value the first time and will not need to be changed. So you won't need the `observeEvent(input$seed, {...})` block or the `checked_query` value